# Putting page inside frame outside caller

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

i am attempting a project in VisualStudio

Having a Window (with a Frame), Page1 and Page2

I am calling Page1 and putting in a Frame from Window. Then in Page1 i want to click a button and put Page2 in Frame and  in Page2 use a method from Page1 to update a table (that is in Page1)

Here i start my window and put Page1 in Frame

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Frame.Content = new Page1();
        }
    }
}
```

Here i start my Page1, update table and want to put Page2 in frame

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Populates table first time
            updateTable();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow.Frame.Content = new Page2();
        }

        private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateTable();
        }

        public void updateTable()
        {
            updateTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i start my Page2 and want to update table from Page1 and go back to Page1

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Page2: Page
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((PageHome)Owner).updateTable();          // Update table from Page1. It gives an error because this is only the way of doing it with windows
            MainWindow.Frame.Content = new Page1();   // Going back
        }
    }
}
```

Dont seem to find a way to do this on the internet. At least this specific situation with pages
Also tried to inherit page1 in page 2 but cant inherit 2 classes

Comment: You can't inherit XAML, you can inherit from classes.

Comment: Don't put the method in page1 or page2. Make it a command you can bind. Put it in a viewmodel which is the datacontext of the window.. Don't use pages, use usercontrols and a contentcontrol rather than a frame. WPF is not asp.net.  If you do this then anything within the window can use any command in the window's datacontext. Page1, page2, page whatever. So long as they are in the contentcontrol they inherit datacontext and can bind to public command properties of that datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate back to `Page1`, you could access it using the `Content` property of the `Frame`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow.Frame.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
    MainWindow.Frame.NavigationService.GoBack();
}

private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frame = (Frame)sender;
    frame.Navigated -= Frame_Navigated;

    Page1 p1 = frame.Content as Page1;
    p1.updateTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions.

I happened not to use these answers

I was able to find something that did what i wanted with this in Page1:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
    }
```

So at least part of the question was answered